# Generate Tables from Entities results in NoInitialContextException

Tags: eclipse, jpa, eclipselink, jboss7.x, java-ee-6

When I try to generate Database Tables from my project's Entities the Exception below is thrown.

If I understand correctly, the Exception suggested to specify `java.naming.factory.initial`:
So I went through several parts of JBoss-Documentation, not quite sure what I was looking for, did experiments with a `jndi.properties`-file and realized in the end that I am absolutely clueless.

BTW: The generation of Entities from Tables (so the other way round) works without problems.

```
[EL Info]: EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461
[EL Severe]: Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-7060] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [java:jboss/datasources/MySQLDS].
Internal Exception: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.cannotAcquireDataSource(ValidationException.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.perform(Main.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.execute(Main.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.main(Main.java:63)
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:103)
    ... 11 more

Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-7060] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [java:jboss/datasources/MySQLDS].
Internal Exception: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.perform(Main.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.execute(Main.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.main(Main.java:63)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7060] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [java:jboss/datasources/MySQLDS].
Internal Exception: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.cannotAcquireDataSource(ValidationException.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:488)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:103)
    ... 11 more
```

my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="DynamicWebProject" transaction-type="JTA">
  <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MySQLDS</jta-data-source>
    <class>hoho.model.generated.AvailabilityDeliveryMethod</class>
    <class>hoho.model.generated.AvailabilityItem</class>
    <class>hoho.model.generated.AvailabilityRestaurant</class>
    <class>hoho.model.generated.Category</class>
    <class>hoho.model.generated.ContactData</class>
    <class>hoho.model.generated.Deliverer</class>
    <class>hoho.model.generated.DeliveryMethod</class>
    <class>hoho.model.generated.DeliveryMethodHasPrice</class>
    <class>hoho.model.generated.Item</class>
    <class>hoho.model.generated.Label</class>
    <class>hoho.model.generated.OrderHasItem</class>
    <class>hoho.model.generated.OrderLimitation</class>
    <class>hoho.model.generated.PaymentMethod</class>
    <class>hoho.model.generated.Person</class>
    <class>hoho.model.generated.PersonPreference</class>
    <class>hoho.model.generated.Price</class>
    <class>hoho.model.generated.PurchaseOrder</class>
    <class>hoho.model.generated.Restaurant</class>
    <class>hoho.model.generated.Tag</class>
    <class>hoho.model.generated.Image</class>
    <class>hoho.model.generated.MimeType</class>
    <class>hoho.model.generated.TaxRate</class>
    <properties>
      <!-- <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/> -->
      <property name="javax.persistence.jtaDataSource" value="java:jboss/datasources/MySQLDS" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: The error states it cannot get the datasource "java:jboss/datasources/MySQLDS".  Are you running this in the server and have you configured the datasource there correctly?  When generating entities, you are using eclipse and its connection to the database.  When generating tables from entities, it looks like it is using JPA and the database connection configured in the persistence.xml - so those connections need to be setup first.

Comment: @Chris Thank you for your answer. 1. The working `generate Entities from Tables` and the non-working `generate Tables from Entities` are both from the `JPA-Tools`-submenu of the context menu I get when doing right click on the project. 2. I am not sure: I think I am not running this in the server. When I try to generate with the server stopped it will stay stopped. And it makes no difference when it is started.

Comment: @Chris I added my persistence.xml to the question.

Comment: I do not believe Eclipse Dali supports generating the tables directly, and instead delegates it to the JPA provider.  In this case, your provider settings are configured to work when the app is deployed to JBoss- you will need to uncomment the eclipselink.ddl-generation property and deploy the app for it to work.  Or you can change the JTA+datasource properties so that it uses Resource_local and a specify the URL settings to use as described here: http://antoniogoncalves.org/2009/07/05/jpa-2-0-standard-properties-in-persistence-xml/

Comment: @Chris I tried both approaches and still get the same exception. What about this `NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial`?

Comment: @Chris After the second approach my JBoss would not deploy anymore dur to an error caused by missing datasource. So I went back to the configuration as posted. Now at least my AS works fine again.

Answer (score 1):

The JPA-Tools are not working with resource type JTA. Change it temporary to RESOURCE_LOCAL.
See also [Generating tables from entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19771723/generating-tables-from-entities/19772106#19772106)

Comment: Unfortunately it seems to be caching the connection data. I changed the connection properties in persistence.xml to a different url/user/pass, but it still connects to the previous one. Can't create objects on new locations like this...

Comment: Ah a login.properties file is created, containing the javax.persistence.jdbc.url, which Eclipse Kepler seems to use when generation entities...