# Generating tables from entities

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, glassfish, eclipselink

I am trying to generate tables from my entities in Eclipse Juno using Project right-click -> JPA Tools -> Generate Tables from Entities

I am using EclipseLink as JPA Provider
My app container is Glassfish 4
My database is the one embedded within glassfish, derby.

My application starts without errors and I am able to commit data to the database using a simple test bean (so I assume my connection pool and datasource are working as intended)

I am getting the following stack trace error when I try to generate the tables from entities:

```
[EL Info]: EclipseLink, version: Eclipsenter code heree Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652
[EL Severe]: ejb: Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-7060] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [jdbc/__planificateur].
Internal Exception: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.cannotAcquireDataSource(ValidationException.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.perform(Main.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.execute(Main.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.main(Main.java:63)
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:103)
    ... 11 more

Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-7060] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [jdbc/__planificateur].
Internal Exception: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.perform(Main.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.execute(Main.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.main(Main.java:63)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7060] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [jdbc/__planificateur].
Internal Exception: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.cannotAcquireDataSource(ValidationException.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:542)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:103)
    ... 11 more
```

Here is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="planificateurepicerie" transaction-type="JTA">
       <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
       <jta-data-source>jdbc/__planificateur</jta-data-source>
       <class>com.whybe.pe.jpa.Ingredient</class>
       <class>com.whybe.pe.jpa.Recette</class>
       <class>com.whybe.pe.jpa.ComposantRecette</class>
       <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
           <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
       </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I also have the database setup in the Database Development perspective and that works fine too.

Inside the glassfish console I can ping the connection pool successfully.

I am running out of ideas as of why the ddl won't generate...

If you need more details let me know!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `transaction-type="JTA"` in a run mode as standalone application. JPA looking for the JNDI resource name in the default context (Wait, currently there is no context in your application, since is a run mode standalone application). Change to `transaction-type="LOCAL"` for that run mode. e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="SamplePU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="123"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="ALL"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

But you are using Glassfish 4. Run the application on the server. If you don't have the JDNI resource name, you need to add it in the JDBC resources. The more easy way is using the console administration of Glassfish. By default, you can find it in `http://localhost:4848`. See more about this in [*Chapter 3 JDBC Resources*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/820-4335/ablih/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! what do you mean by "in a run mode as standalone application." ? I set the transaction-type to JTA because I want the container to manage the transactions for me

Comment: That solution works though, so I marked it as Answered. I need to figure out the JTA one though otherwise I can't inject the EntityManager